# Town Portal bugs?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm in the necro campaign of M&MH 6, and I have had repeated trouble using town portal spells. I've got two towns that have both a Basic and Advanced town portal in them. Because an enemy hero was moving towards a fort somewhere, I wanted to teleport back to one of these towns (advanced town portal), and then teleport to that fort (basic town portal) in order to defend it.

However, after teleporting back to my main town, I can not use the Basic teleport from there. I tried waiting a few turns, but the spells of both teleports remain greyed out. I have enough mana and movement points. This issue has arisen several times now.

Is there something I'm not getting about these teleports? To use basic teleport, I have to be: 
- in a town with a basic town portal
- have enough mana and mov points

Anything else? Because it's not working.

Also, it bothers me that even though I have two towns with advanced town portal, I can not choose which one to go to when using advanced town portal. It seems to just pick one of the two.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use both Advanced Town Portal and Basic Town Portal on the same turn, even if you have the necessary movement points.

There are a couple possibilities here:

- Is the town portal basic effect cursor coming up at all? (Looks like the same symbol for Magic Power) If it's not coming up at all, that's likely a bug. Your best bet is to simply quit / reload the game.
- If the cursor *is* coming up, and your target is valid, you've likely just triggered one of Heroes' VI's many bugs, and you best bet is reloading / restarting the game.

Comment: Forts are valid Town Portals to, you just can't Town Portal back from them.

Comment: @MrSmooth So they are. Just verified this myself.

Comment: I think these comments should be in the other answer. No?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your last question/problem the Advanced Town Portal spell says in the description that it teleports you to the *nearest* friendly town with an Advanced Town Portal building.

Your Advanced Town Portal spell is probably grayed out because you are already in the town it would teleport you to, so casting it would do nothing. You can test this by taking a step away from your town and see if the spell is available again.

From your description it does sound like you should be able to use the Basic Town Portal spell to teleport to your other town. You should make sure that the other town does not have two hero in it. If the other town is completely occupied, you will not be able to cast the spell.

If the target town is not full and and you still cannot cast the spell, it is probably a bug, so you should try saving and reloading to fix the problem.

As the others have said, you cannot use either Town Portal spell to teleport to the fort anyway because the spells only allow you to teleport to towns, and forts are not towns.

Comment: Your 3rd paragraph isn't true. Two heroes can share a town. Three can't, though. Additionally, you don't need any town portal buildings in the target town (basic TP only).

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks, I fixed the information in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug.

You need to go back to a save game when you still can use town portal advance. If you don't have one, you're going to have to restart the campaign.

It can happen to any faction campaign; It's not about gameplay tactics, it's  about how unlucky you are.

Comment: Think I've experienced this now and it's only the case for my main hero for some reason. Rather annoying...

Answer (score 0):

With Advanced TelePortal you do not necessarily go to the closest town. I noticed in Circum Radiant Dawn campaign that I transfer to the town with highest rank in this case rank 4 from a captured town. A touch annoying because I am teleported to the underground world where nothing is happening anymore because the area is secured from any enemies.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and ended up hiring a hero that could Town Portal (Basic) to protect a town in jeopardy. Had to build a tavern to recruit the hero... and suddenly Town Portal (Advanced) became available.

Answer (score -1):

This bug will self resolve upon completing the map, you do not have to restart the campaign if this is possible.